# imagecreatefrompng(): '/home/ubuntu/dv8.png' is not a valid PNG file

Tags: php, image, png, gd

My code:

```
    $filepath = '/home/ubuntu/dv8.png';
    echo "mime content type: " .mime_content_type ($filepath) . "<br />";
    $image_src = imagecreatefrompng($filepath);
    print_r($image_src);
```

It outputs:

```
mime content type: image/png
Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): '/home/ubuntu/dv8.png' is not a valid PNG file in /var/www/test.php on line 2
```

Any ideas why I would get this? Would it have to do with my PHP version possibly? 5.3.2

phpinfo() and under the GD section lists:

```
PNG Support enabled
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: can you upload that image somewhere ?

Comment: I'm also getting errors with png. I create with GD a thumbnail from png file, and when i want to process it again, i get "is not a valid png file". I've opened it and file structure doesn't look as png, but the file can be opened in image viewer, etc.

Comment: I never did figure out the source of this issue. I made a lot of code changes since this post and I think users are only using JPGs at this point, so I don't know if this is still an issue or not. Would be very interested if anyone has any ideas though.

Comment: @Slowfib: Next time also upload the image somewhere so others can try to reproduce. Image formats often have variants, sometimes some libraries are not supporting every single bit of a format for reading and/or writing.

Comment: perhaps `/home/ubuntu/dv8.png` is not a valid PNG file?

Answer (score 1):

I get problems mainly with the transparency when i use a PNG file that is not saved in 'indexed' mode.

To change a PNG from RGB mode to indexed mode, open it in gimp and go to
IMAGE-> MODE-> INDEXED

and export it again.  See if that fixes it.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.